# Linear layout with autosize doesnt work

Tags: ios, autolayout, autosize

I need to create following layout, the problem I have in it is the times when "This can stretch" views do grow in height but using struts and springs solution I'm using right now doesnt work. I've tried to programatically set new position based on current height of subview but this doesnt work as well. Can someone help me with this setup? I dont really understand the auto layout as all my attempts fails. The view stack looks like this:

- Details

  - View

    - Scroll View

      - Content View

        - view 1
        - view 2
        - view 3 - can grow in height
        - view 4
        - view 5
        - view 6
        - view 7 - can grow in height, also this can be hidden if not used
        - view 8 - this can be hidden if not used
    - CSToolbar view

the CSToolbar is a view attached to bottom of screen, scroll view stretches on all window size and has the content insets set to include navigation bar and CSToolbar height.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I know, it's not very easy task to make **UIScrollView** content work with auto layout.
Maybe, [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) can throw light on your problem.

Other way is to use **UITableView** instead. **view 1..8** would be cells in it. And you could specify cells' heights using appropriate **UITableViewDelegate**'s method.
Also you may create subclass of **UIScrollView** and override **layoutSubviews** method. And there you could set all views' frames explicitly.

Comment: can I have static cells and some dynamically added cells in that table view?

Comment: No, you can't. But it's not a big deal, since you can create different cell prototypes with different reusableIdentifier-s in storyboard and return them in data source in desired order. And take a full control of them in code.